# How can I handle an error when using transactions, and the table is using the myISAM engine instead of InnoDB?

Tags: php, pdo, transactions, innodb, myisam

The beginTransaction function in php does not return false when the database is not using the myISAM engine by default, or if tables are using myISAM instead of InnoDB.

How, then, can you error handle when this occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link where I can query the database and see if the table is myisam or innodb...but i don't know if thats the best solution.  I would have to check before every query if the table is myisam or innodb.         [How do I find if my a table is MyISAM or Innodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681790/how-do-i-find-if-my-a-table-is-myisam-or-innodb)

Comment: also found this link worth mentioning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659155/why-does-my-php-transaction-not-work/9659366#9659366

Comment: I guess what I can do is check all tables im querying in the transaction and check if they're all innodb.